# Data set structure

Tags: dataset

I'm having problem to understand how my dataset should be organized. I have unbalanced panel data with observations of products' prices as independent variable. Data is from a 3-year period.

Simplified version:

[image]

Now, I want to include annual GDP per capita, population, income per capita as instrumental variables.

Where should I put it - to the columns to the right for overy observation? Should I choose the value from the same year in which the product was observed or year before?

Can someone please provide an example. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What analysis in which software have you planned?

Comment: @Momo I have Minitab and Eviews. So far, I have used mostly Minitab. In addition, an example in Excel may suffice just to get an idea.

Comment: @Momo I overlooked the first question. I am going to do regression analysis with 2SLS. Currently I am stucked with this issues and I want to check the proper way to organize my data.

Comment: +1 if only because people don't ask this question enough

Comment: Can anyone please provide an example?